# PhoneGap 2.5 FileTransfer.download callbacks don't fire

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, download, file-transfer

I'm puzzled by why this isn't working.My code is below. I making a FileTranser.download() call that never reach the success or fail functions. I can see the progress console.logs and it even reaches 1. I can also see debug messages saying that the file was successfully transferred from a CDVDelegate class. In my iPad Simulator, I can even see that the file is created. I just can't get my success handler to trigger.

I was only able to find mention of this as an issue back in around PhoneGap 1.8. Is this still an outstanding issue or am I holding it wrong?

Thank you

```
var fileName ='my-file.pdf';
var ft = new FileTransfer();
var docPath = localStorage.getItem(CONSTANTS_LOCALSTORAGE_LOCAL_FILE_PATH);
var encodeduri = encodeURI(CONSTANTS_WEBAPI + 'Documents/GetDocument?DocFilename=' +fileName + '&DocumentType=' + documentType);
console.log(encodeduri);

ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
  console.log('download progress: '+(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total));
} };

ft.download(
  encodeduri,
  docPath+"/"+fileName,
  function(entry){
    //------ Never reaches this
    console.log('download ok: '+entry.fullPath
    onSuccessCallback(entry);
  },
  function(error) {
        //-------or this
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
        onFailCallback(error);
    }, 
  false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this issue, I fixed it by deleting the app from the device and refreshing the Xcode project.

Comment: What do you mean, "refreshing the xcode project". I don't even use xcode in my cordova project, I just let cordova call it whenever it needs. Is there a "refresh" option in xcode or something? I did try deleting the app from the device and retying (cordova run ios), but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: If you do have a reliable fix for this, you should get notify the cordova guys as there are open issues concerning this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6905, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6525